# What is the most precise antonym of "innate"?

Tags: antonyms

I want to say that something is extremely challenging for both intrinsic and extrinsic reasons - for example, doing research on something happening on Neptune (intrinsic - Neptune is harder to observe) that is also politically charged (extrinsic - the politics get in the way of objectivity but are external to the thing itself).

I *can* say that, of course - I just did. But what if I wanted to use 'innate' (for its innate in-bornness) rather than 'intrinsic'? What is its antiword, if it exists? Perhaps some Latin way to say 'not inborn'?

Edit: I'm really specifically into reasons here, not skills or behaviours. An acquired vs. innate skill and a learned vs. innate behaviour are all well and good, but I don't think they are as good a fit for reasons.

Comment: You probably need to try to clarify your question. As far as I can tell, you already used a word for what you mean: external. You might look for synonyms to *external, secondary, indirect, tangential, attendant, remote, distal.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can consider ***adventitious*** for reasons and ideas that are not innate.

It comes from from Medieval Latin *adventitius* "coming from abroad, extraneous," a corruption of Latin *adventicius* "foreign, strange, accidental," from *advent-* past participle stem of *advenire* "arrive". <sup>[[etymonline]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=adventitious)</sup>

> - coming from another source and not inherent or innate [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adventitious)
> - Coming from outside or from an external source; added or occurring as a result of an external factor or of chance, rather than by design or inherent nature; extraneous, foreign; incidental. [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2917?redirectedFrom=adventitious#eid)

---

Differences between *innate* and *adventitious* ideas from a philosophical standpoint:

> One view on the nature of ideas is that there exist some ideas (called *innate ideas*) which are so general and abstract that they could not have arisen as a representation of any object of our perception, but rather were in some sense always present. These are distinguished from *adventitious ideas* which are images or concepts which are accompanied by the judgment that they are caused or occasioned by an external object.
>
> <sub>[Audi, Robert, ed. (1995). Cambridge Dictionary of Philosophy]</sub>

Comment: I'm giving this answer based on OP's clarification. OP eliminated "acquired" and "learned" and OP already used "external" and "extrinsic" which might not fit.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with *acquired*, as in an acquired skill.

> **acquired**
>   *adj*.
>   1. Gained by one's own efforts. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquired)

Innate qualities require no effort.

Comment: I also agree with 'acquired'.

Answer (score 2):

Another word is [learned](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/learned):  acquired by experience, study, etc. As in
learned behavior.